# Polymorphic or has_many :through for recording cash flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

So far I've spent a day trying to model the following, which I believe should be simple, I've looked at it too much, and there is probably an obvious solution staring at me..

Objective: `Users` book `clients` onto `events` which can be chargeable, users access `cashbox` area to account for payments for those `chargeable events`(money in), `other_charges`(money in)but only related to clients) and record general `expenses`(money out)unrelated to events or clients).

So far: User, Client and Event model created with correct associations. Typical scenario; user books client onto event, that can be chargeable (boolean).

```
# == Associations so far

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  has_many :events
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, through: :events
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Problem: Should the associations for `cashbox` be polymorphic or has_many :through?

They way I understand it using polymorphic; events, other_charges & expenses could be `cashboxable`. The downside to this is I understand I can't `sum` over polymorphic associations?

With has_many through I am confused how to associate this, it seems complicated. But I could be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  has_many :events
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, through: :events
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :client
end
```